# Tkinter - How can I detect when the main window is resizing?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

in my software, when the user uses the mouse cursor to resize the main window, the message "window resizing" should appear in a label widget, instead when the user doesn't do that, the label widget should be "ready". how can I reach this behaviour?

below my code, but it's incomplete, because I really don't know how to write it. can someone help me please?

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):

        self.parent=tk.Tk()
        self.parent.title("TEST")
        self.parent.minsize(350, 300)

        self.label=tk.Label(self.parent, text="Ready")
        self.label.pack()
        
        self.parent.bind("<???>", self.resizing)    # ???
        self.parent.bind("<???>", self.no_resizing) # ???
        
        self.parent.mainloop()
    
    def resizing(self, *args):
        self.label.configure(text="window resizing..")
    def no_resizing(self, *args):
        self.label.configure(text="ready")
    
app=MainWindow()
```

Comment: `<Configure>` event for resizing and moving.

Comment: @acw1668 `<Configure>` triggs only the activities made in the title bar, if I resize the main window using its other sides, there aren't events. in addition, with `<Configure>` I can't understand when the user stops to resize the window. it's not so simple, ..

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to the `<Configure>` event. Be aware that due to how tkinter processes events, any bindings on the root window will apply to every child of that window. It's best to test for the root window inside the callback.

There is no event for when the window stops being resized. A simple solution is to use `after` to schedule the changing of the label after a small delay. You can reset that job each time the callback is called.

It might look something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):

        self.parent=tk.Tk()
        self.parent.title("TEST")
        self.parent.minsize(350, 300)

        self.label=tk.Label(self.parent, text="Ready")
        self.label.pack()

        self.parent.bind("<Configure>", self.resizing)

        self.parent.mainloop()

    def resizing(self, event):
        if event.widget == self.parent:
            if getattr(self, "_after_id", None):
                self.parent.after_cancel(self._after_id)
            self.label.configure(text="window resizing...")
            self._after_id = self.parent.after(
                100, lambda: self.label.configure(text="ready")
            )

app=MainWindow()
```

Comment: I used to bind to [Expose](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bind.html#M15) event, since it doesn't fire on dragging the `window` for example. It makes it easier to distinguish between the events, if that's the goal.